# How to split array 10W5N2S6E

Tags: javascript

I need to split `"10W5N2S6E"` into `[10W,5N,2S,6E]`

I have written:

```js
var a = "10W5N2S6E"
var splited = a.split("W", "E", "S", "N")
console.log(splited)
```

Comment: Try `a.split(/(?<=[NESW])/)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` here with the regex pattern `\d+[A-Z]+`:

```js
var input = "10W5N2S6E";
var matches = input.match(/\d+[A-Z]+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

If you wanted to use a split approach, you could split on the lookarounds `(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)`:

```js
var input = "10W5N2S6E";
var matches = input.split(/(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/);
console.log(matches);
```